# NullPointerException on Custom Adapter

Tags: android

I am getting an error i can't solve.

Here is my code:

private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter
    {

```
    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
            Contact[] listc) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, listc);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list, parent, false);
        Contact[] items = listc;

        ImageView iv = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.contact);
        tv.setText(items[position].getFName()+" "+items[position].getName());

        Log.w("myApp", tv.getText().toString()); // Used to be sure that the text isn't null

        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent); //Line 55 (troublemaker)
    }
}
```

And here is the log:

```
04-27 02:59:45.955: D/dalvikvm(13179): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 6ms
04-27 02:59:45.955: W/myApp(13179): Alain Sagna
04-27 02:59:45.955: D/AndroidRuntime(13179): Shutting down VM
04-27 02:59:45.955: W/dalvikvm(13179): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4116a2a0)
04-27 02:59:45.960: E/AndroidRuntime(13179): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-27 02:59:45.960: E/AndroidRuntime(13179): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-27 02:59:45.960: E/AndroidRuntime(13179):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:395)
04-27 02:59:45.960: E/AndroidRuntime(13179):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
04-27 02:59:45.960: E/AndroidRuntime(13179):    at com.fsd.fashioner.MainMenu$MyAdapter.getView(MainMenu.java:55)
04-27 02:59:45.960: E/AndroidRuntime(13179):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2461)
04-27 02:59:45.960: E/AndroidRuntime(13179):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1775)
04-27 02:59:45.960: E/AndroidRuntime(13179):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:678)
```

Answer (score 1):

change the return statement

return row;

as return super.getView(position, convertView, parent); contain the covvertview which is empty  and throws the null pointer exception.

Comment: I replaced the return statement but i'm still getting the null pointer exception.
*******************************************************************

04-27 13:33:23.574: E/AndroidRuntime(22501): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-27 13:33:23.574: E/AndroidRuntime(22501): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-27 13:33:23.574: E/AndroidRuntime(22501):  at com.fsd.fashioner.MainMenu$MyAdapter.getView(MainMenu.java:51)
04-27 13:33:23.574: E/AndroidRuntime(22501):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2461)
04-27 13:33:23.574
********************************

But now the error is in line 51

Comment: comment these lines and check it:tv.setText(items[position].getFName()+" "+items[position].getName());

        Log.w("myApp", tv.getText().toString());

Answer (score 0):

```
        View retval = null;
        retval = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.custom_list, null); 
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) retval .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        TextView tv = (TextView) retval .findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.contact);
        tv.setText("just to check "); 
        return retval;
```